# app engine: ImportError: No module named Crypto.Hash

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycrypto

I have a script that uses `Crypto.Hash` but import fails with error:

```
ImportError: No module named Crypto.Hash
```

in my `sys.path` if I print the `sys.path` list, there is this entry (among others):

```
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/pycrypto-2.6
```

If I open the path above, there is no pycrypto-2.6 directory.

How can I get to load pycrypto 2.6?

If I import `Crypto.Hash` running python from command line it works

I have to point out that pycrypto is supported by App Engine, it is included in [this list](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27).

Furthermore I have included the module in my `app.yaml` file:

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: lxml
  version: "2.3"
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

If I send the code in production on appengine it works, the problem is in my system I should probably download a compiled version of pycrypto and put it somewhere appengine can use it

Comment: in my case the library is included in the list of supported libraries by appengine

Comment: Oups.. right :) The you will have to include it in the app.yaml.. did you do that?

Comment: I retracted the closed vote as I didn't notice that it was on the list..

Comment: thanks, if I send the code in production it works, it is a problem on my system

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: my os is OS X 10.9.5

Answer (score 15):

It seems a problem that happens on MAC OSX, all I have managed to do is following:

firstly you need to know where your install of pycripto is, running

```
sudo pip install pycrypto
```

either you install the library or you get the path where it is installed

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycrypto in
>   ...

then, considering that this is a problem that does not happen in production on appengine, I did this:

```
try:
    from Crypto.Hash import SHA
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/[mypath]/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
    from Crypto.Hash import SHA # requires PyCrypto
```

Answer (score 1):

**Run the SDK from the command line with `dev_appserver.py`, rather than with the GUI** (assuming you've already checked that it's installed via `pip`).

I've seen similar problems with App Engine not importing libraries locally, even though they're installed, and even though they work fine in production. MySQLDB comes to mind, although I can't find the reference. Anyway, this worked for me.